# The specified child already has a parent.must removeView first

Tags: android, android-view, android-tablelayout

I just got this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` I'm not sure why it's saying this or how to fix it... here is my code where the error is occuring:

```
public void createTable(String xmlForTable) 
    throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
//public void createTable(){

    Integer i = 0;
    endPlacementTag = "nothing";
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_tires);

     lo = (TableLayout)  findViewById(R.id.tiresTable);

     TableRow headerRow = new TableRow(this);
     TableRow.LayoutParams hp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     headerRow.setLayoutParams(hp);

     tv = new TextView(this);
     tv.setText("Text Header");
     headerRow.addView(tv);
     lo.addView(headerRow);

     XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
     factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
     XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

     xpp.setInput(new StringReader (xmlForTable));
     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

     TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        num = new TextView(this);
        projectNumber = new TextView(this);
        inspectionLotNumber = new TextView(this);
        serialization = new TextView(this);
        spec = new TextView(this);
        sku = new TextView(this);
        materialNumber = new TextView(this);

     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

              System.out.println("Start document");

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

              System.out.println("End document");

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
              placementTag = xpp.getName();

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

              System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
              endPlacementTag = "End tag "+xpp.getName();

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

              System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());



              //If the text tag is equal to "Table" do nothing otherwise...
              if(placementTag.equals("Table"))
              {
                  //Do Nothing
              }
              else if(placementTag.equals("NUMBER"))
              {
                  num.setText(xpp.getText());
                  //row.addView(num);
                  placementTag = "";

              }
              else if(placementTag.equals("ProjectNumber"))
              {
                  projectNumber.setText(xpp.getText());
                  //row.addView(projectNumber);
                  placementTag = "";

              }
              else if(placementTag.equals("InspectionLotNumber"))
              {
                  inspectionLotNumber.setText(xpp.getText());
                  //row.addView(inspectionLotNumber);
                  placementTag = "";

              }
              else if(placementTag.equals("Serialization"))
              {
                  serialization.setText(xpp.getText());
                  //row.addView(serialization);
                  placementTag = "";

              }
              else if(placementTag.equals("Spec"))
              {
                  spec.setText(xpp.getText());
                  //row.addView(spec);
                  placementTag = "";

              }
              else if(placementTag.equals("SKU"))
              {
                  sku.setText(xpp.getText());
                  //row.addView(sku);
                  placementTag = "";

              }
              else if(placementTag.equals("MaterialNumber"))
              {
                  materialNumber.setText(xpp.getText());
                  //row.addView(materialNumber);
                  placementTag = "";

              }
              else if(endPlacementTag.equals("End tag Table")) 
              {

                  row.addView(num);
                  row.addView(projectNumber);
                  row.addView(inspectionLotNumber);
                  row.addView(serialization);
                  row.addView(spec);
                  row.addView(sku);
                  row.addView(materialNumber);

                  lo.addView(row,i);
                  i++;

              }

              }
          eventType = xpp.next();
          }

     try {
        xmlParser(tableXml);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Here is my logcat:

```
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251): Process: cooper.tirerfid, PID: 1251
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at cooper.tirerfid.AllTiresActivity.createTable(AllTiresActivity.java:331)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at cooper.tirerfid.AllTiresActivity$1.run(AllTiresActivity.java:433)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-05 10:42:13.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 433 of my code is in this chunk of code:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.i(TAG, "createTable() has started");
            try {
                createTable(tableXml);
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "createTable() has completed");


       }
   });
```

With line 433 being `createTable(tableXml);`

Comment: 331 is actually where your problem is. And the error is pretty explicit

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and make sure you aren't calling addView() more than once with the same parameter